# Convert org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.SimpleGroup to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record

Tags: java, avro, parquet

I am writing code to convert a large parquet file that I have as rows of:

```
List<org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.SimpleGroup>
```

to small single row parquet files, each one requiring an org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record.

When I am building the single row files I am doing something like:

```
for (int a = 0; a < parquet.getData().size(); a++) {

            // one row of input data
            SimpleGroup simpleGroup = parquet.getData().get(a);

            String aaa = simpleGroup.getString("aaa", 0);
            String bbb = simpleGroup.getString("bbb", 0);
            String ccc = simpleGroup.getString("ccc", 0);

            // output record
            GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);
            record.put("aaa", aaa);
            record.put("bbb", bbb);
            record.put("ccc", ccc);

            // covert record using schema
            byte[] bytes = recordInjection.apply(record);

            data.add(bytes);
        }
```

While I show just three columns there are many columns.  It seems like I should be able to somehow call:

```
byte[] bytes = recordInjection.apply(record);
```

on the simpleGroup or neatly iterate over all rows of the simpleGroup building up the GenericData.Record, but I cannot figure out how.

Does anyone know how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found was that I could iterate through fields from the schema:

```
      for (Schema.Field field :avroSchema.getFields()) {
                String name = field.name();
                record.put(name, simpleGroup.getString(name, 0));
            }
```